# Switch Case in Android to Replace Image by another image. Something like the Tinder Image swapper

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want the current Image to be replaced by another image when I tap the image, and the second image to be replaced by a third image when I tap the second image and so on. I want to do this for 3 or more images.

I have done this with a very trivial technique but I want to do the same thing using a switch case so that the code is more intuitive and its more efficient when there are multiple images.

activity_main.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:rowCount="14"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/stephen_carvalho_bald"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="513dp"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:contentDescription="@string/home_image_cd"
        android:onClick="changeImage"
        android:src="@drawable/stephen_carvalho_bald" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/stephen_carvalho_golden_pagoda"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="573dp"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:onClick="changeImage"
        android:contentDescription="@string/home_image_cd"
        android:src="@drawable/stephen_carvalho_bhandardhara_lake"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/stephen_carvalho_hackathon"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="573dp"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:onClick="changeImage"
        android:contentDescription="@string/home_image_cd"
        android:src="@drawable/stephen_carvalho_hackathon"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_row="11"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:fontFamily="@font/anton"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_row="12"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:fontFamily="@font/anton"
        android:text="@string/home_page_button"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

</GridLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```java
package com.example.helloworld;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageView mImageView;
    private ImageView m1ImageView;
    private ImageView m2ImageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mImageView = findViewById(R.id.stephen_carvalho_bald);
        m1ImageView = findViewById(R.id.stephen_carvalho_golden_pagoda);
        m2ImageView = findViewById(R.id.stephen_carvalho_hackathon);



        mImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                mImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                m1ImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
        m1ImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                m1ImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                m2ImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
        m2ImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                m2ImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                mImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, i think you should consider to use a RecyclerView for that, you don't need three different ImageViews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Whatever, here you go, a working switch for your app, happy coding dude!**

```
package com.example.helloworld;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private ImageView mImageView;
    private ImageView m1ImageView;
    private ImageView m2ImageView;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mImageView = findViewById(R.id.stephen_carvalho_bald);
        m1ImageView = findViewById(R.id.stephen_carvalho_golden_pagoda);
        m2ImageView = findViewById(R.id.stephen_carvalho_hackathon);

        mImageView.setOnClickListener(this);
        m1ImageView.setOnClickListener(this);
        m2ImageView.setOnClickListener(this);

        }

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.stephen_carvalho_bald:
            mImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            m1ImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Toast.makeText(this, "You clicked view1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        case R.id.stephen_carvalho_golden_pagoda:
            m1ImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            m2ImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Toast.makeText(this, "You clicked view2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        case R.id.stephen_carvalho_hackathon:
            m2ImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            mImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Toast.makeText(this, "You clicked view3", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;

         }
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add all your images in a list:

```
private ArrayList<Integer> images = new ArrayList<Integer>();
images.add(R.drawable.image1);
images.add(R.drawable.image2);
images.add(R.drawable.image3);
...
```

Have just one ImageView and on its clickListener parse the list with every click and set a new drawable as a background resource:

```
    int counter = 0;
    mImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View view)
                {
                   mImageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(YourActivity.this, images.get(counter))); 
                   counter++;
                   if (counter >= images.size()) {
                       counter = 0;
                   }
                }
            });
```

The way I have it, it would recycle the list, but you can break the cycle by setting the appropriate check on the counter above.